# SingleShotMode: picture taken not being showed up on Samsung Note 3

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'm using cwac-camera library to take pictures in my app.
I've written my own CameraHost class which overrides useSingleShotMode method so it returns true.

It w works great on a few devices that I used for testing, but my problem is that I can't seem to make it freeze the preview after taking the picture on Samsung Galaxy Note 3.

Any help ?

Comment: Does single-shot mode in the demo app work?

Comment: Yes single-shoot mode mode work in demo app work. In my case shoot-mode work on all other device excapt on Note 3.

Comment: Try to determine what you are doing different than the demo app, then, with respect to single-shot mode.